parsing Jmeter variable to OS process sampler
I am having trouble parsing Jmeter varibles to OS Process Samplers.
I currently have a beanshell sampler that get the sampleresult of the previous sampler like so:
String uploadResults="";

if(sampleResult.isSuccessful()){
    uploadResults = "true";
    vars.put("uploadResults", uploadResults);
} else {
    uploadResults = "false";
    vars.put("uploadResults", uploadResults);
}

I then have an OS Process Sampler that runs a .ps1 script with the following configuration:

Command: ${powershellPath}
Command parameter: powershell.exe -noexit ""& `${shellScriptPath}` '`${loginResults}`' 'Upload'""

My .ps1 script outputs the result like so:
Write-Host "${result}"

.ps1 result
When I started the script, the OS Process Sampler returned an output like so when the condition is "false":
False result
And like so when the condition is "true":
True result
Not sure what is going here, I suspect that is has something to do with the jmeter variable encoding. Any help would be appreciate.
EDIT: Here is the .ps1 code. I have redacted some information but the main functionality is there.
param (
    [string]$result,
    [string]$transaction,
    [string]$eventSource = "JMeterEventSource",
    [string]$logName = "Application",
    [int]$eventID = 4200
)
 
# Check if the event source exists, if not, create it
if (-not [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($eventSource)) {
    New-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $eventSource
}

if($result -eq "false"){
    switch ($transaction) {
        "Upload" { $eventMessage = "FunctionalTransactions Script - upload-verification Sampler - The transaction ${transaction} is unavailable" 
                   $eventType = "Error"
                   $eventID = 4211
        }
        "Login" { $eventMessage = "FunctionalTransactions Script - login-verification Sampler - The transaction ${transaction} is unavailable" 
                   $eventType = "Error"
                   $eventID = 4211
        }
    } 
}
else {
    switch ($transaction) {
        "Upload" { $eventMessage = "FunctionalTransactions Script - upload-verification Sampler - The transaction ${transaction} is available" 
                   $eventType = "Information"
                   $eventID = 4210
        }
        "Login" { $eventMessage = "FunctionalTransactions Script - login-verification Sampler - The transaction ${transaction} is available" 
                   $eventType = "Information"
                   $eventID = 4210
        }
    }   
}


 
# Write the event to the log
Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $eventSource -EntryType $eventType -EventID $eventID -Message $eventMessage
 
Write-Host "${result}"


I cannot reproduce your issue using the following OS Process Sampler configuration:

and the following Powershell script:
Write-Host "Result is: "$args[0]


So I guess nothing is wrong with "encoding" of JMeter Variables, you should take a closer look into your powershell script and the way you're handling the variables there.
So far I can only give you one piece of advice: using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern, consider switching to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language. See Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For? article for more details.

Hi, thank you for your reply. I have tried with the JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy and still get the same result. Here is my groovy code:
String loginResults="";
if(prev.isSuccessful()){
loginResults = "true";
vars.put("loginResults", loginResults);
} else {
loginResults = "false";
vars.put("loginResults", loginResults);
}
